# The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing from your computer. Simple console

Tags: c++, crash, console

Please help. I am using Code Blocks, and I have just built a project and now when I try to run the ".exe" it says this message "The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing from your computer...this problem." I have tried to download those .dlls and extract them into the location where the ".exe" is stored and then tried running the program again but it crashes. I have no idea what to do anymore.
Can anyone give me steps to solving this using Code Blocks(IDE. that I use)? Please.

Another note that I'd like to add is that I am learning C++ and I do not understand complicated lingo like "linker", "links", and etcetera. I want this application to be stand-alone if possible but I have searched around about this issue and people are saying to place the related .dlls from the bin of minGW where your executable is but then they say that there is licensing issues. I am getting confused about this and I just want a simple fix, I don't want any licensing issues.
Can you explain it from Code Blocks point of view? Because that's the program that I am using, and some steps to fix it would be really nice.
Note 3: People are also saying to use something like "-static-libgcc" but I have no idea what to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

The `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` should be in the compiler's `bin` directory.

You can add this directory to your **PATH** `environment variable` for runtime linking, or you can avoid the problem by adding `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` to your compiler flags.